# Reviewing Method Analyzed with Time Profiler

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have used the Time Profiler Instrument to identify a significant lag in my app. Now I know what the problem is, but I don't know what to do about it. I am using ARC and have a viewController that calls the method "Go" as below. I have included a snapshot of the Time Profiler result as well. Does anyone know how I might resolve this? Thank you!

**This is the code for the method:**

```
- (void)go {

CGFloat width = self.imageViewA.bounds.size.width;

[UIView animateWithDuration:18.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
animations:^ {
    self.imageViewA.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageViewA.frame, -width, 0);
    self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageViewB.frame, -width, 0);
    } 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (self.keepGoing) {
        // now B is where A began, so swap them and reposition B
        UIImageView *temp = self.imageViewA;
        self.imageViewA  = self.imageViewB;
        self.imageViewB = temp;
        self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, 
        self.view.bounds.size.width, 0.0);
        // recursive call, but we don't want to wind up the stack
        [self performSelector:@selector(go) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
    }];
}
```

**This is the result of my Time Profile:**

[image]

**For reference, I have also included my .h file.**

```
@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *lButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rButton;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL keepGoing;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageViewA;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageViewB;

- (IBAction)handleLPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)handleRPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: Normally this isn't a heavy call and it should be fast enough to not block your main thread. Note: 'self' is copied onto the stack because you reference it in a block. If self is a large object then I can imagine the copy could take a while (and thus blocking UI).

Comment: Thanks Robyn, should I be releasing this or setting it to NIL somewhere? its basically an image that continuously slides across the screen...

Comment: @RobinvanDijke, why "'self' is copied onto the stack"? It is retained. It shouldn't take time at all. But still, it is better not to use self inside a block...

Comment: @MichaelKessler Indeed, you are right. It is retained instead of copied. My bad.. Than this should not take time

Comment: @Brandon, the animation is the only thing that is done in this method. What would you expect to see? That `CGFloat width = self.imageViewA.bounds.size.width;` takes 90% of time?

Comment: You are right... Made me realize the method wasn't what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work:

```
- (void)go {

CGFloat width = self.imageViewA.bounds.size.width;

__weak typeof(self) self_ = self;

[UIView animateWithDuration:18.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
animations:^ {
    __strong typeof(self) self = self_;
    self.imageViewA.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageViewA.frame, -width, 0);
    self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageViewB.frame, -width, 0);
    } 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    __strong typeof(self) self = self_;
    if (self.keepGoing) {
        // now B is where A began, so swap them and reposition B
        UIImageView *temp = self.imageViewA;
        self.imageViewA  = self.imageViewB;
        self.imageViewB = temp;
        self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, 
        self.view.bounds.size.width, 0.0);
        // recursive call, but we don't want to wind up the stack
        [self performSelector:@selector(go) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
    }];
}
```

What this does is keeping a weak reference to self instead of copying it in the block to the stack. I am not sure, but maybe this could work.

Comment: Thanks Robin! Checking it out now!

Comment: Hi Robin - still getting the same lag. I have added my .h file to the question as well in case that has any helpful info.

Comment: Could you also post your stack trace? It seems to me that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Is there a way to just release it on viewDidUnload or something - its causing problems in subsequent view controllers.

Comment: What do you mean by it? And `viewDidUnload` is only called upon memoryWarnings

Comment: Sorry - The app doesn't actually lag on the view controller that the "Go" method is being called from. It lags later in the app as the user clicks around other viewControllers. Im assuming that something created in the method isn't being removed/deallocated properly or something along those lines.

Comment: As said before: `self` is retained in the blocks (twice, completion and animationBlock). This could cause a [retain cycle](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html) which causes self not to dealloc. Using the __weak reference solves this. But maybe there is more that is lagging :)

Comment: Hi Robin - figured out what the problem was, not actually related to the Go method. You were right saying it might be elsewhere. Thank you!!